# Clustering List of Strings

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, hierarchical-clustering, fuzzy-search

Let's we have this kind of long list:

```
list = ['computer','computers 12','old computer','laptop','lap top','laptops']
```

Is there any method to convert similar strings into categories into clusters? For longer text, the algorithms like [LDA](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/79360_850b2a69980c4488b1db95987a24867a.html) are based on words, not the characters. There is also [fuzzy-wuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) a library for checking similarity but it just checks the similarity of pair of words. By the way, I want to get this kind of output:

```
output = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
```

Where 1 reflects the computers, 2: laptops based on their similar writings.

Answer (score 0):

After tedious algorithmic work, I wrote a solution like [this](https://gist.github.com/suatatan/4f2f5a582f3eed7d5b2ececd643f8b96). It simply assigns a similar name as a cluster rather than numbers.

```python
import WordCluster
list = ['computer','computers 12','old computer','laptop','lap top','laptops']
wcu = WordCluster(list,4)
cluster_categories = wcu.find_cluster_categories()
categorized_words =wcu.categorize_all_words(self.cluster_categories)
print(

categorized_words)
```

The result became like this. The name of the cluster is automatically generated from our initial list and 'old computer' i.e. is the last type of computer-like word and 'laptop' is also for the latter series.

```python
[{'word': 'computer', 'cluster': 'oldcomputer'},
 {'word': 'computeri', 'cluster': 'oldcomputer'},
 {'word': 'oldcomputer', 'cluster': 'oldcomputer'},
 {'word': 'laptop', 'cluster': 'laptop'},
 {'word': 'lap top', 'cluster': 'laptop'},
 {'word': 'laptops', 'cluster': 'laptop'}]
```